# Redirect non existing link with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

We have a static site example.com built with custom php. When we type example.com/asdadada it redirects to the custom 404 page. But when we type example.com/about-us/asdadada, it stays on the same url, i.e. example.com/about-us/asdadada and content of about-us page is shown. We need a 404 or 301 redirection under such circumstances. We have used the below code in htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

#get rid of trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#redirect to https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} view [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://example.com? [R=404,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: So `/about-us` gets rewritten to - what? `/about-us.php`? `/about-us/index.php`? // The order in which you are doing stuff here is rather uncommon, usually all external rewrites that deal with stuff like HTTPS redirects, www to non-www or the other way around, trailing slashes etc., should all come first.